# songs played in windows media player results in noise and lagging

Tags: laptop, cpu, windows-media-player, speedfan

Whenever a song is played in windows media player, I hear a noise followed by lagging in the song as if somebody is controlling the speed of the song.

Also the sound of fan in my laptop could be heard very loudly.
Nowadays it is getting heated very fast and sometimes turns off automatically due to overheat.
Please give me a solution.

Comment: Have you tried something like VLC player? VLC player usually works much better than windows media player.

Comment: :I have no problem with VLC player.But I never faced such an issue with the WMP before.Just to make sure everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your music stored on your computer or are you streaming it live? If streaming, it could be download amount controls.

Does your music play with film (video) and not just music? If with film you can, to make it a little lighter to run, convert the video to music only with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/#download) or [YTD](http://www.ytddownloader.com/).

Have you tried to play your music with another player? This will let you know if it is only WMP. Try VLC, etc. [as stated in [cokedude's](https://superuser.com/users/93715/cokedude) answer]. You should find the **Event Reports** (in Admin tools) for this as they could provide a **error ID** from which you can refine the search for a solution.

Does your fan make noise and over heat while doing anything other - say watching a film? Turning itself off is on the serious side and you should check the fan and CPU.

**CPU tests**:

- [CPU test 1](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/)
- [CPU test 2](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2297/techpowerup-gpu-z-v0-7-4/mirrors)
- [CPU test 3](http://realtemp.en.lo4d.com/)

**Fan test**:

- [Fan test 1](http://speedfan.en.lo4d.com/)

Putting all this aside, it could be that you have copied the music one to many times and it has missed some bits. If this is a possibility, try and find an older backed up version and see how the new copy works (this is what happened to me and how I fixed it).

Answer (score 0):

Go here:

http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml

And run the DPC Latency Checker. You may be having a problem with a mis-behaving kernel mode driver.